# How to separate the values of a line of .csv file which contains commas in data?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

I have a 1.2GB of `.csv` file and the row of that file contains commas"," in the data part. I am using node.js to convert CSV to JSON file.
The header row contains:

```
ID,Case Number,Date,Block,IUCR,Primary Type,Description,Location Description,Arrest,Domestic,Beat,District,Ward,Community Area,FBI Code,X Coordinate,Y Coordinate,Year,Updated On,Latitude,Longitude,Location
```

The data looks like this:

```
6340381,HP428814,07/02/2008 12:00:00 AM,013XX W ARDMORE AVE,0890,THEFT,FROM BUILDING,OTHER,false,false,2013,020,48,77,06,1166245,1938965,2008,02/04/2016 06:33:39 AM,41.988100417,-87.663899454,"(41.988100417, -87.663899454)"
```

See the last data i.e. `location` contains value `(41.988100417, -87.663899454)` which contains comma. How should I separate it.

Comment: Are you converting manually or using some csv parser?

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: I am doing it manually

Comment: You should use something like `csv` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv), it will handle everything for you and it works great.